# Complex numbers in fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

> Evaluate the expression and write your answer in the form $a+bi$.
> $$\overline{\left(\frac8i\right)}$$

How do I answer this question? I originally wrote $-8 + 8i$ but it was wrong.

I don't understand what the overline means.

Comment: Overline means complex conjugate.

Comment: $\overline i=-i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac 8i = m + ni$ then $\overline{\frac 8i} = m - ni$.  The overline indicates the complex conjugate.

The easiest way to get this is to solve

$\frac 8i = x$.

$\frac 8ii = xi$

$8 = xi$

$8i = xi^2 = -x$

$x = -8i=0-8i$

And $\overline x = 0+8i = 8i$.

A general rule of them is that if $z = a + bi$ and $\overline z=a-bi$ then $z\overline z = a^2 + b^2\in \mathbb R$, so to ever put a fraction with complex numbers into proper form you multiply   the denominator by its conjugate.  That is

$\frac zw = \frac {m+ni}{a+bi} = \frac {m+ni}{a+bi}\frac{a-bi}{a-bi} = \frac {(m+ni)(a-bi)}{a^2 +b^2}= k + ji$ where $k = \frac {ma+bn}{a^2 + b^2}$ and $j=\frac{na-bm}{a^2 + b^2}$.

So to solve

$\frac 8i = \frac 8i \frac {-i}{-i} = \frac {-8i}{1} = -8i$ and $\overline{\frac 8i} = \overline{-8i} = 8i$.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have $8/i=-8i$. The overline signifies complex conjugation; $a+bi$ becomes $a-bi$. So we get the final result as $8i$ or $0+8i$.

Answer (score 0):

Every complex number $z$ can be written in the form
$$
z=a+ib
$$
where $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $i$ is one of the two solutions to the equation
$$
X^2+1=0
$$
usually called imaginary unit.

The real numbers $a$ and $b$ are respectively called *real* and *imaginary part* of the complex number $z=a+ib$.

At this point, one defines the *conjugate* of $z$ (denoted as $\bar z$) simply by changing the sign of its imaginary part; that is
$$
\bar z=a-ib\;.
$$

Coming to your problem:
$$
\overline{\frac 8i}=\overline{\frac{8i}{i^2}}
=\overline{-8i}=8i\;
$$
(here the real part is zero).